# cannot read property of undefined while json is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a json array in an html page but I keep getting

> cannot read propery of undefined

at 
`var opleidingArray = VragenEnScores.vragen[index].opleidingen;`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var VragenEnScores = {
    "vragen":[
      {"nummer":1, 
       "opleidingen":[
         {'naam':'3D artist', 'scores':[10,20,30,400], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'3D print productdesigner', 'scores':[5,2,8,4], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'Aannemer installateur centrale verwarming/ combi solar thermal', 'scores':[0,2,9,4]}
         ]
      },
      {"nummer":2, 
       "opleidingen":[
         {'naam':'3D artist', 'scores':[1,2,3,4], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'3D print productdesigner', 'scores':[5,2,8,4], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'Aannemer installateur centrale verwarming/ combi solar thermal', 'scores':[0,2,9,4]}
         ]
      },
      {"nummer":3, 
       "opleidingen":[
         {'naam':'3D artist', 'scores':[1,2,3,4], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'3D print productdesigner', 'scores':[5,2,8,4], 'resultaat':0}
         ,{'naam':'Aannemer installateur centrale verwarming/ combi solar thermal', 'scores':[0,2,9,4]}
         ]
      }
    ]
  };

  var antwoordenPerVraag = [3,4,7,8];
  var resultatenPerOpleiding = new Object();

  antwoordenPerVraag.forEach(berekenEindresultaten);

  function berekenEindresultaten(item, index) {
    var opleidingArray = VragenEnScores.vragen[index].opleidingen;

    var params = {antwoord: item};

    opleidingArray.forEach(haalScoresOp.bind(params));
  }

  function haalScoresOp(item, index) {

    if (isNaN(resultatenPerOpleiding[item.naam])) {
      resultatenPerOpleiding[item.naam] = 0;
      resultatenPerOpleiding[item.naam] += item.scores[this.antwoord];
    } else {
      resultatenPerOpleiding[item.naam] += item.scores[this.antwoord];
    }
  }

  var sortable = [];
  for (var resultaat in resultatenPerOpleiding)
        sortable.push([resultaat, resultatenPerOpleiding[resultaat]])
  sortable.sort(
      function(a, b) {
          return b[1] - a[1]
      }
  )

  $('#resultaat').text(sortable);



});
</script>
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: my guess is index is 3 or greater

Comment: Once you put `~@antwoorden~` in quotes *(which is a different problem)*, it works just fine. https://jsfiddle.net/nq9ro4gh/

Comment: Did I forget how to JavaScript, or is `var antwoordenPerVraag = [~@antwoorden~];` nonsense?

Comment: @stijn That is a variable coming from a automation system that loads before the page is generated.it looks like an array after loading [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Can you post the actual output then, the way the client receives and parses it? Also, it would be better to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise your question risks being closed.

Comment: As a sdie note, you should always use english name for variable, especially when asking for help on an english forum. Actually, your code is quite unreadable

Comment: Okay Edited the post and will try to keep everything in English.

Comment: @depperm is right, your looping four times when you do "antwoordenPerVraag.forEach(berekenEindresultaten)" but only have 3 values in "VragenEnScores.vragen", so in your loop when it tries to reach 'VragenEnScores.vragen[3]' it's undefined.

Comment: It was indeed a looping problem, now it works!